# About : Android cocos2d debug.py command

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am facing an issue while debugging a project which is build in cocos2d.
Please tell me what to do.
i have already done sdk,ndk ,ant, python setup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

search "Build dynamic library for project" in build_native.py, you can find out where the exception is raised. then you can find out the problem by debugging with log message.

i think maybe the problem is "G:\Android is not recognized as an internal or external command"